# Unhandled exception error Visual Studio 2012 and Allegro 4

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, allegro

I´m using allegro 4.4.2 on Visual Studio 2012 for a school project. Allegro is installed and working, and I'm trying to get it to load a map.txt file which is located in the project folder. When debugging, allegro freezes and becomes incredibly slow and throws an unhandled exception, violation access code at me.

This is Map.h:

```
#include <allegro.h>
#include "Global.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Map
{
    public:
         Map();
        ~Map();


        void Init();
        void Update();
        void Draw(BITMAP *Buffer);

        void LoadMap (const char*filename);
    private:
        int loadCounterX;
        int loadCounterY;
        int mapSizeX; 
        int mapSizeY;
        int MapFile[20][15];
};
```

And this is Map.cpp:

```
#include "Map.h"

Map::Map()
{
}


Map::~Map()
{
}

void Map::Init()
{
    loadCounterX = loadCounterY = 0;
    Map::LoadMap("map1.txt");
}

void Map::Update()
{

}

void Map::Draw(BITMAP *Buffer)
{
    for (int i = 0; 1 < mapSizeX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++)
        {
            if (MapFile[i][j] == 1)
            {
                rectfill(Buffer, i*BlockSize, j*BlockSize, i*BlockSize + BlockSize, j*BlockSize + BlockSize, makecol(0, 255, 255));
            }
            else if (MapFile[i][j] == 2)
            {
                rectfill(Buffer, i*BlockSize, j*BlockSize, i*BlockSize + BlockSize, j*BlockSize + BlockSize, makecol(0, 255, 0));
            }
        }
    }
}

void Map::LoadMap(const char*filename)
{
    ifstream openfile (filename);
    if (openfile.is_open())
    {
        openfile >> mapSizeX >> mapSizeY;
        while (!openfile.eof())
        {
            openfile >> MapFile[loadCounterX][loadCounterY];
            loadCounterX ++;

            if (loadCounterX >= mapSizeX)
            {
                loadCounterX = 0;
                loadCounterY ++;
            }
        }
        loadCounterX = loadCounterY = 0;
    } //File is opened
    else
    {
        allegro_message ("Map File couldn't be found");
    }
}
```

and here is my main file:

```
#include <allegro.h>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Global.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Map.h"
using namespace std; 
volatile int counter = 0;

void Increment ()
{
    counter ++;
}

int main (void)
{
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    install_mouse();
    install_sound(DIGI_AUTODETECT, MIDI_AUTODETECT, "A");
    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode (GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0, 0);

    LOCK_VARIABLE (counter);
    LOCK_FUNCTION (Increment);
    install_int_ex (Increment, BPS_TO_TIMER(100));

    BITMAP *Buffer = create_bitmap (6000, ScreenHeight);
    bool done = false;

    Player player;
    Camera camera;
    Map map;

    player.Init();
    camera.Init();
    map.Init();

    while (!done)
    {
        while (counter > 0)
        {
            //Input
            if (key[KEY_ESC])
                done = true;

            //Update
            map.Update();
            player.Update();
            camera.Update(player.x, player.y);
            counter --;
        }

        //Draw
        map.Draw(Buffer);
        player.Draw(Buffer);
        camera.Draw(Buffer);
        clear_bitmap(Buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

It crashes at this line

```
if (MapFile[i][j] == 1)
```

everytime. All of the variables shown in "Autos" in Visual Studio turn red; "MapFile" "MapFile[i]" (which I don't understand.. shouldn't this just be "i"?) "j" "mapSizeY" and "this" However when I expand the "MapFile", the first 20 blocks are filled out correctly as they are in my map.txt file.
I'm completely lost and have no idea what to do... any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In `void Map::Draw(BITMAP *Buffer)` you use `1 < mapSizeX` instead of `i < mapSizeX`

Comment: And `mapSizeX` and `mapSizeY` are never initialized, from what we can see.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the 1 instead of i. I've been looking over this for ages. Thank you so much.

Comment: @LogicStuff  `openfile >> mapSizeX >> mapSizeY;`

Comment: @Simon I missed that, because I was looking for initializations in the constructor. If `LoadMap` is not called, crash awaits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `void Map::Draw(BITMAP *Buffer)` you use `1 < mapSizeX` instead of `i < mapSizeX`.

You might also want to prevent calling `Map::Draw` when the `Map::LoadMap` wasn't called before.